# Concurrency in multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was giving mock test for ocjp 6 exam and encountered the following question on Concurrent access:

```
public class Cruiser {
   private int a = 0;

    public void foo() {
        Runnable r = new LittleCruiser();
        new Thread(r).start();
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Cruiser c = new Cruiser();
        c.foo();
    }

public class LittleCruiser implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
            int current = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                current = a;
                System.out.print(current + ", ");
                a = current + 2;
            }
    }
}
```

What are the possible outputs ?

options:

A) 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 6,

B) 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

C) 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4,

D) 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14,

E) 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

Answers are A and B.

My doubt is, how can option A be a possible output? I mean if first thread enter it's run method, it will change the value of a , and if in between second thread comes it will get the changed value of a,so how come numbers are repeated ?
please explain this problem , thanks in advance!

Comment: If a statement is on a single line it doesn't mean it gets executed in a single cpu cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Neijwiert , can you please elaborate

Comment: I just got 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 2, 4, 6,  which is different than A and B :)

Comment: @Veselin Davidov , can you please explain the reason for this output?

Comment: This is a really bad question (the mock question I mean).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

IF there were no racing conditions the answer would be always B) because you increment the same variable. But this is not the case because in this code:

```
 current = a;
 System.out.print(current + ", ");
 a= current + 2;
```

You set current=a (which has some value), use it for printing but during that time another thread may have modified a. And then when you set a=current+2 you override that other threads change.

For example if the steps are:
Initially a=0;

1. Thread 1 current=a; (T1 current = 0)
2. Thread 2 current=a; (t2 current also = 0)
3. Thread 1 prints current -> 0
4. Thread 1 sets a=current+2 -> a=2;
5. Thread 2 prints its own current which is still 0 set in step 2
6. Thread 2 sets a=current+2 -> a=2 basically overriding step 4 which occurred in the other thread

So you can get other possible answers too like:

0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6,

0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 2, 4, 6,

0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 6,
etc.

It depends on the way the threads are executed and what has happened between when we set current to something and then set a back to current+2

Comment: no problem but others seem to disagree because I keep getting downvotes ;) I might have missed something

Comment: I have no idea why my answer was the accepted solution and then I got 2 down votes and then another answer is the accepted solution which basically says the same... whatever

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible scenario, where:

- Column a is the value of a.
- Thread 1 is the action of thread 1
- The first current is the value of current for the thread 1
- Thread 2 is the action of thread 2
- The second current is the value of current for the thread 2

Here the steps:

```
a        Thread 1     current     Thread 2    current
----------------------------------------------------------
0        current = 0     0 
0                                 current = 0    0
0        current = a     0
0                                 current = a    0
0        print curr      0                                // Prints 0
2        a = current+2   0
2        current = a     2
2        print current   2                                // Prints 0, 2
4        a = current+2   2
4        current = a     4
4        print current   4                                // Prints 0, 2, 4
4                                 print current  0        // Prints 0, 2, 4, 0
2                                 a = current+2  0
2                                 current = a    2
2                                 print current  2        // Prints 0, 2, 4, 0, 2
4                                 a = current+2  2
4                                 current = a    4
4                                 print current  4        // Prints 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4
6                                 a = current+2  4 
6        a = current+2    4
6                                 current = a    6
6        current = a      6
6        print current                                     // Prints 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6
6                                 print current            // Prints 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 6
```

Note that this is not the only possible scenario because some operations can be inverted between thread 1 and thread 2 (for example the last two couples)

Answer (score 0):

> I mean if first thread enter it's run method, it will change the value
>   of a

yes

> and if in between second thread comes it will get the changed value of
>   a

not so certain, the updated value may not be visible to the second thread. See [Memory Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html):

> Suppose a simple int field is defined and initialized:
>
> `int counter = 0;`
>
> The counter field is shared between two threads, A
>   and B.
>
> Suppose thread A increments counter:
>
> `counter++;`
>
> Then, shortly afterwards, thread B prints out counter:
>
> `System.out.println(counter);`
>
> If the two statements had been executed
>   in the same thread, it would be safe to assume that the value printed
>   out would be "1". But if the two statements are executed in separate
>   threads, the value printed out might well be "0", because **there's no
>   guarantee that thread A's change to counter will be visible to thread
>   B — unless the programmer has established a happens-before
>   relationship between these two statements**.